# Is it bad practice to loop a thread every 1s while activity is opened?

Tags: android, loops

I have an app, which works with dates and times and also an progress bar, which indicates the percentage of time elapsed time from one date to another. So if date1 is 2019-07-05 05:00 pm and date2 is 2019-07-05 07:00 pm and current time is 2019-07-05 06:00 pm the percentage is 50% because 50% of the time from date1 to date2 is remained.

And on activity start, I calculate the percentage of time and set this value with setProgress() to the progress bar. There is no problem yet and everything works. My question now is whether I can create a thread, which sleeps for 1s and then calculate the new percentage, because the current time has changed, and set value to progress bar. This will be repeated every 1 second until activity is finsihed. Is that a bad method? I thought about performance, when running code every 1 second. Is this a good practice? Can I do so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a `Timer` or `Handler` instead

```
    final Handler handler = new Handler();

final Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        updateProgress();
        handler.postDelayed(this, 1000L);
    }
};

void doWork() {
    // do one of these, either handler or timer
    handler.post(runnable);

    new Timer().schedule(new TimerTask() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            updateProgress();
        }
    }, 0L, 1000L);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's a crucial part of your app then it's not really bad. You could even loop every 1/60 of a second so your bar is updated in 60fps and there would be no problem with it.

But I would suggest using a `Timer`, because you're only repeating every second and it's also easier to stop it.

Comment: Thank you so much! I will take the timer.